# Deleted nib still displayed when controller is pushed

Tags: iphone

I have an application with a UINavcontroller under a tab bar controller.  To create the navigation model I want, I push a container UIView object onto the stack to manage additional views(Thanks Frank).  When I created the container class, an associated nib file was created along with it.  I at first used that nib file, but it turned out it was better not to.  So I deleted the nib (and selected 'also move to trash').  The problem is that it still shows up when I push its view controller onto the stack.  I have tried emptying the cache in xcode and restarting xcode.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I imagine there can be a copy left in the app bundle that is created in the `build` directory. Try doing a `Clean All` and compile again.

Answer (score 0):

1) Stop your project and run Product->Clean (or shortcut `<Shift>` + `<Command>` + `<K>`)

2) Right click on the project name at the root of the Groups & Files tree on the left side of your project window, and select "Open in Finder". In the Finder window, locate the Build folder and delete it;

3) If still not working
do a search for your xib in the Goups tree and in every volumn off your environment (Finder->File->Find...).